# Infopath form load rule set value filter not working

Tags: query, infopath-rules, sharepoint-list-filter

This is driving me crazy.  Super user here (not IT).  I have an infopath form tied to populate a sharepoint list.  On a field in my form, I have a drop down list.  I want to populate that drop down list from another SharePoint list.  I have a data connection established to the SharePoint list and have unchecked the auto load feature.  I then set a rule on form load with two actions:  "Set a field's value" and "Query using a data connection".  I have a filter on the "set a field's value" that is not filtering, it is just giving me the entire column of data from the SharePoint list.  My secondary data connection is "Unit Master"  I Have three columns I am pulling in: 1) UnitName (text field), 2) IsActive (boolean field), 3) AssetType (text field).  I want the query to only retrieve to  UnitNames where IsActive is true and AssetType is Unit.  Here is my rule details:
Field:  UnitName (from the query fields from Unit Master (Secondary))
Value: UnitName[AssetType="Unit"and IsActive=string(true())]  - Unit Name is selected from the data fields from Unit Master (Secondary).  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks so much!
[image]

Comment: I finally figured it out.  First I dragged the query fields and data fields to my form so that as I play around with the set a fields value filter I could see what it was doing.